# New symbol of infinity similar to a 'w' or omega

Tags: symbols

I would like to have a symbol that is similar to a w ou a omega, and I want it to be made from the infinity symbol `\infty` by 'erasing' the top part of it. I would prefer to trim out only the "upper v" part of the infinity symbol, as to have the new symbol resemble more an omega.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @mrf I wish to use it as the omega of ordinal numbers and so I want it to resemble the traditional infinity symbol.

Comment: There is a reason that notation is more or less standardized. If you mean the first infinite ordinal, just use $\omega$, otherwise your readers will be needlessly confused.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the original guidance to trim the upper part, one can adjust the `.4\LMex` clipping amount to suit the desired look.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip,scalerel}
\newcommand\altinfty{\ThisStyle{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt .4\LMex}{$\SavedStyle\infty$}}}
\begin{document}
$\lim x \rightarrow \altinfty$

$\scriptstyle\lim x \rightarrow \altinfty$

$\scriptscriptstyle\lim x \rightarrow \altinfty$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Based on a comment by the OP, an alternative, rather than clipping, is to overlay a strategically placed white rectangle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\altinfty{\ThisStyle{\stackinset{c}{-.1pt}{t}{-.08\LMex}
  {\textcolor{white}{\rule{1.5\LMex}{.6\LMex}}}{$\SavedStyle\infty$}}}
\begin{document}
$\lim x \rightarrow \altinfty$

$\scriptstyle\lim x \rightarrow \altinfty$

$\scriptscriptstyle\lim x \rightarrow \altinfty$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should cut it even more to make it more like omega. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano OK, I upped it to `.4`.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Is it possible to only trim out the "upper V", so that it looks more like an omega? I wish to use it as the omega of ordinals and the resemblance with the traditional infinity symbol is on purpose.

Comment: I think this should be called the Moustache operator (+1).

Comment: @Marijn I was kind of partial to the `\dollyparton`...

Comment: It also reminded me of https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/45209/tarass.

Comment: +1 (as always `;-)`) for the realization, but as a theoretical physicist I must say that no one will ever understand what this means `:-(`

Answer (score 12):

Clip *three* copies of `\infty` and superimpose them to each other.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\badomega}{\mathord{\mathpalette\bad@omega\infty}}
\newcommand{\bad@omega}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \clipbox{0pt 0pt {0.75\width} {0.2\height}}{$\m@th#1#2$}\hidewidth\cr
    \hidewidth\clipbox{{0.75\width} 0pt 0pt {0.2\height}}{$\m@th#1#2$}\cr
    \clipbox{0pt {-0.05\height} 0pt {0.55\height}}{$\m@th#1#2$}\cr
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\badomega\scriptstyle\badomega\scriptscriptstyle\badomega$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will work also over a colored background.

[image]

Comment: Very beautiful all answers that I have much appreciated. They look like the mustaches :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful since I want it to work over a background of any color.